# Struggling with regex in Pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

I'm trying to remove characters from the start of string column in pandas to tidy up some addresses but struggling to find the best regex to do the job.

The general format of the text is is something like:

```
1 / BAA Temporary Building, Land Opposite Park
3 / BAC Methodist Church Hall, Park Drive, Bar
4 / BSA St Annes Church Hall , Lynton Avenue
```

And my instruction:

```
df.address.str.replace(r"\d+ / [A-Z]{3}", "")
```

This works for most cases, but returns a blank for cases such as:

```
2 / BAB, BAD Barlaston Village Hall, Longton R
```

or

```
6 / BSC, BSD Holy Trinity Church Hall
```

How do I provide an optional argument to pick up the extra three-character element?

Comment: Would this do : `df.address.str.replace(r"^[0-9]+ [/] [A-Z]{3}(, [A-Z]{3})* ", "")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df['cut'] = df.address.str.replace(r"\d+ \/ [A-Z]{3}", "").str.replace(r'^,\s+[A-Z]{3}', '')

In [210]: df
Out[210]:
                                          address                                      cut
0  1 / BAA Temporary Building, Land Opposite Park   Temporary Building, Land Opposite Park
1  2 / BAB, BAD Barlaston Village Hall, Longton R        Barlaston Village Hall, Longton R
2  3 / BAC Methodist Church Hall, Park Drive, Bar   Methodist Church Hall, Park Drive, Bar
3    4 / BSA St Annes Church Hall , Lynton Avenue     St Annes Church Hall , Lynton Avenue
4          6 / BSC, BSD Holy Trinity Church Hall                 Holy Trinity Church Hall
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you. I didn't realise you could chain str.accessor methods.